# What is integral of a function of a differential?

Tags: calculus, integration, differential

What is $$\int \dfrac{d\theta}{\sin\frac{d\theta}{2}}$$

I thought of approximating the $\sin$ term $$\sin \dfrac{d\theta}{2} \approx\dfrac{d\theta}{2}$$ and so the integral evaluates to be
$$\int 2$$

which is wrong as comments have highlighted.

---

### Where it was encountered

This is a problem I encountered while finding the tension force on a ring due to rotation about its central axis.

[image]

From figure:

- The dark grey vector is infinitesimal Tension $dT$
- The angle between the dark blue radii is $d\theta$, and half it is $\frac{d\theta}{2}$
- light gray vector $ = dT \cos\frac{d\theta}{2}$
- red vector $ = dT \sin\frac{d\theta}{2}$

Observe that $\cos$ component of $dT$ will cancel, and $\sin$ components will add up.

These $\sin$ components will provide the necessary centripetal force for rotation, therefore:

$$2\rm{dT}\sin\frac{\mathbb{d\theta}}{2} = \dfrac{v^2 \mathbb{dm}}{r}$$

But $\rm dm = \lambda dl \ $ and $ \rm dl = rd\theta$ ($\lambda$ = linear mass density)

So we finally get:

$$\rm 2dT\sin\frac{d\theta}{2} = \frac{\lambda v^2 r d\theta}{r}$$

$$\rm \frac{2}{\lambda v^2}\int dT = \int \frac{ d\theta}{\sin\frac{d\theta}{2}}$$

$$???$$

Comment: That approximation is only valid in physics.

Comment: What situation would lead you to take the sine of a differential? Then divide that into a differential? I believe Leibniz would say that you have your units wrong: the sine of a differential would be a differential, and dividing that into a differential gives a real number (perhaps with a differential added on), which cannot be integrated. (I don't know the equivalent argument in non-standard analysis.)

Comment: Assuming the approximation, the integrand would be $\frac{d\theta}{sin(\frac{d\theta}{2})}\approx 2\cdot \frac{d\theta}{d\theta}$
Cancelling the infinitesimals away wouldn't make sense since you're throwing away the information regarding wrt to what you're integrating

Comment: I'll add the derivation in a moment

Comment: Correct we lost the differential to whose respect we integrated!

Comment: @Tim: Have you verified your initial (very nicely done btw) sketch of the problem is indeed correct ?

Comment: $\int 2 = C+2+2+2+\dots \to \infty$

Comment: I think the problem is that it shouldn't be $dT$ but rather just $T$?

Comment: @jim You are correct! Thank you! Please add this as an answer so i can accept.

Comment: The final answer comes out to be $T = \lambda v^2$ using the approximation $$\sin\dfrac{d\theta}{2}\approx \dfrac{d\theta}{2}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that it shouldn't be $dT$ but rather just T.

Answer (score 1):

I think thats not right the reason is dimensional analysis. Dimensions of force are $[MLT^{-2}]$ While if you somehow integrate it (which i dont know how) you will get only an a constant as integral of $\sin(x)$ is just another trigo ratio here $-\cos(x)$ which is dimensionless even if $x$ has dimensions like those of phase in wave optics ie $sin(kx-\omega t)$ thus i think you have made a mistake in your derivation.

Comment: Its not the complete integral my dear friend! I only posted the relevant bit here!

Comment: Okay you said youll add in a moment $51$ mins ago so i thought you forgot

Comment: I took quite a lot of time sorry.